# Can I add a description to routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I just found a nice trick, via [this blog post](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/list-all-rest-endpoints/). Now, after Express thing, I have this simple print:

```
var routes = app._router.stack;
var Table = require('cli-table');
var table = new Table({ head: ["Name"] });
//var table = new Table({ head: ["Name", "Description"] });
for (var key in routes) {
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = routes[key];
        if(val.route) {
            var _o = [val.route.path];
            // but I'd like it to be:
            //var _o = [val.route.path, val.route.descrition]
            table.push(_o);
        }
    }
}
console.log(table.toString());
console.log('');
```

I'd like to add programmatically a description. Something like:

```
app.get('/', function{
    this["description"] = "a nice description";
    // ...
});
```

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: `this.["description"]` certainly isn’t, as it’s not correct JavaScript syntax. You’d want `this["description"]` or `this.description`.

Comment: yes, sorry was a type. anyway does not work..

Comment: There's no reference to the description in your loop.